# How to increase the normal or given font-size values little bit more in wicked-pdf

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, css, ruby-on-rails-2, wicked-pdf

I have a body content in my wicked-pdf report with variable font-size

If i add font-size to paragraph like

```
p {
   font-size: 16px !important;
}
```

then whole paragraph font-size will become 16px, there may be a word containing 22px font-size also in that paragraph
 so i need to increase the font size to their normal font-size values

for example

If the word containg font-size 16px then i should make that to 17px; or if the word containing font-size 22px; then i should increase to 23px; in my pdf report

I mean If my tag contains the value `<p style="font-size:16px">` then it should convert to `<p style="font-size:17px">`

I mean i need to increase or adjust the font-size values little bit more to their normal size values in my pdf report

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass in a value for `zoom` that is equivalent to zooming the page of a web browser:

```
render :pdf => 'mypdf', :zoom => 1.5
```